# Lower the time that chrome tells me that "I have gone full screen"

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I go full screen in chrome, this message appears:

[image]

It stays up for a very long time and blocks everything behind it. Is there a way to lower the time it shows to around 2 seconds? I do not want to disable this message, I just want it to annoy me less.